# How to calculate SD of sample for one new observation?

Tags: standard-deviation

In below example, Is it possible to calculate new SD for one additional observation?

> In a class of 25 students, 24 of them took an exam in class and 1
>   student took a make-up exam the following day. The professor graded
>   the first batch of 24 exams and found an average score of 74 points
>   with a standard deviation of 8.9 points. The student who took the
>   make-up the following day scored 64 points on the exam.

New mean is 73.6, What is new SD? How to calculate it?

Comment: I think this might be a near duplicate of [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72212/updating-variance-of-a-dataset)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes,** it's possible. Taken from [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/103025/83386), the updated mean and standard deviation (SD) can be calculated as follows:
$$
\bar{X}_{n} = \frac{1}{n}\left(X_{n} + (n - 1)\bar{X}_{n-1}\right)
$$
Where $n$ is the sample size (including the new observation), $X_{n}$ the value of the new observation $\bar{X}_{n-1}$ is the mean of the $n-1$ first observations.
For the standard deviation, we have:
$$
s_{n} = \sqrt{\frac{n-2}{n-1}s_{n-1}^{2}+\frac{1}{n}\left(X_{n} - \bar{X}_{n-1}\right)^{2}}
$$
Where $s_{n-1}^{2}$ denotes the variance of the $n-1$ first observations.

Using the numbers $n=25, \bar{X}_{n-1}=74, s_{n-1}^{2}=8.9^{2}=79.21, X_{n}=64$, we get:
$$
\begin{align*}
\bar{X}_{n} &= 73.6 \\
s_{n} &= 8.939216
\end{align*}
$$